# Why does the following require any integral value of m and n

Tags: limits

The original question required finding the values for which $nx + m = nx^2 + m$ where $x$ approaches $1$.

You can very easily see the equation being $n + m = n + m$. Naturally i concluded that any value of $n$ and $m$ will do. But the solution is listed as "Any integral value of $n$ and $m$". What the heck is a integral value of $n$ and $m$? Why is it necessary? Why can't it be any natural/real/rational/irrational number?

Update: The original question was:

If $f(x) = $

$mx^2 + n, x < 0$

$nx + m, 0 \le x \le 1$

$nx^3 + m, x \gt 1$

For what integers $m$ and $n$ does $lim_x->1 f(x)$ exist?

Comment: What is the exact statement of the original question?

Comment: An integral value means a value that is an integer. The rest of the question is not clear.

Comment: @GregMartin Updated with original question.

Comment: Well, the question asks specifically for m and n to be integers...

Comment: It's true that there seems to be no good reason the question restricted $m$ and $n$ to be integers; the problem works perfectly well for any real numbers $m$ and $n$. But the chosen statement of the question explains why the answer is given as it is.